# How do I auto-start my Commerce Minions?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I've configured a Minion for my Sitecore Commerce solution. We're on 8.2.1.

It's set up like this:

```
  {
    "$type": "XYZ.Commerce.Plugin.Custom.Policies.QueuePolicy, XYZ.Commerce.Plugin.Custom",
    "ConnectionString": "[redacted]",
    "WakeupInterval": "00:05:00",
    "QueueName": "preprod",
    "Models": {
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Model, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
      "$values": [
      ]
    }
  }
```

I've been following this guide: https://websterian.com/2017/06/08/sitecore-commerce-erp-integration-an-approach-part-1-integrating-orders-and-customers/

Wherein it states:

> Minions are designed to be run on schedule, the default is every five
>   minutes but this can be changed in your environment file as per this
>   example…

[image]

But this doesn't appear to be enough. My Minion still needs to be kickstarted via a post (as described elsewhere in the same linked article).

So I must be overlooking something. How can I ensure, my Minion is always up and running on a specified interval, in plain configuration?

Comment: you can log info when your minion was started or was finished

Comment: The Minion runs fine, if I start it manually with a `commerceops/RunMinion()` call. If I don't make this PUT request (via Postman), the Minion never runs.

Comment: This may be specific to Commerce 9, but each `MinionPolicy` attached to an environment will be run when the environment starts up (via a block on the `IStartEnvironmentPipeline`). How is your MinionPolicy defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reference your minion inside configure method (found in the Commerce.Engine project, Startup.cs):

You will have something like:

```
public void Configure(
       IApplicationBuilder app,
       IConfigureServiceApiPipeline contextPipeline,
       IStartNodePipeline startNodePipeline,
       IConfigureOpsServiceApiPipeline contextOpsServiceApiPipeline,
       IStartEnvironmentPipeline startEnvironmentPipeline,
       ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
       IOptions<LoggingSettings> loggingSettings,
       IOptions<ApplicationInsightsSettings> applicationInsightsSettings,
       IOptions<CertificatesSettings> certificatesSettings)
       {
         //your code
         startEnvironmentPipeline.Run("yourminion", _nodeContext.GetPipelineContextOptions());
       }
```

Comment: I don't think this step is necessary, if you call the bootstrap command to load the JSON change to SQL Server.

Comment: Hey @DanSolovay on Sitecore 9 is not necessary to have it.

Comment: on Commerce 9, you mean. But on 8.x it was necessary.

Comment: Yep Commerce 9 :)

Comment: Guys, thanks for clarifying.  I was deep in solving this issue with 9, and missed the qualification in your question. Updating my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

An additional note: For Sitecore Commerce XC 9 (not 8.2.1 as in original question), it is no longer necessary to invoke it from the Commerce.Engine project, as long as you've run the Bootstrap command (located in the SitecoreCommerce_DevOps Postman collection) to get the configuration loaded to SQL Server. After that step your minion should run as normal.