# What is the correct syntax to run the startEnvironmentPipeline?

Tags: pipelines, sitecore-commerce

This is a follow-up question to the question asked here: [How do I auto-start my Commerce Minions?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/how-do-i-auto-start-my-commerce-minions)

In the line:

```
startEnvironmentPipeline.Run("yourminion", _nodeContext.GetPipelineContextOptions());
```

In what format should I put the replacement for "yourminion"?

I have tried the FullyQualifiedName from the minion policy and I have tried just the class name and something halfway between the two of them but all three gives an error when I start the Engine:

4 15:20:06 ERROR Core.block.LoadEnvironment.EnvironmentCouldNotBeFound: Environment=X

(where X is whatever I used to replace "yourminion")

Comment: can you verify in the minions folder if you have  config.json and inside you will have somethingn like {"AppSettings":{"SiteTitle":"Sitecore Commerce Engine","BootStrapFile":"Global","DeploymentId":"Deployment01","EnvironmentName":"HabitatMinions","EncryptionProtectionType":"Machine","EncryptionCertificateHash"//

Comment: if you have something similar you have to use : "HabitatMinions" or what name you have

Comment: Ah it's the name of the Environment file and not the individual minions? That make so much sence now. I will give that a try right away. Thank you.

Comment: please try, unfortunately I don't have Commerce 8.2.1 installed but as far I remember  environment name  is used

Comment: It looks like that did the trick. Atleast I do not get the same error any longer. Now I only need to verify that it acctually do what I wanted it to do in the first place. But in either case, thank you very, very much. It was a great answer that saved me alot of time figouring it out.

Comment: I will change my comment into an answer. Please market as correct, maybe it will help others in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because you need to use Environment name on

```
 startEnvironmentPipeline.Run("EnvironmentName",_nodeContext.GetPipelineContextOptions());
```

instead of FullyQualifiedName from the minion policy or the class name.